# File Upload in Angular FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have a formArray with file upload (input) in each formArray element but when upload image in input file will change other file inputs's value in other rows.

[image]

**Current Behavior:** Whenever I upload file in an input file, this file appearing in the value column of all row.

**Excepted Behavior:** Whenever I upload file, this file should appear in the value column of that row only.

can anyone help me :( ?

this is html code in my **component.html**

```html
<div formArrayName="familyMembers">

  <div *ngFor="let group of SonArray;let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">

    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12">

      <!-- another input fields html code -->

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <img id="imagu" class="img-fluid imgo " src="assets/img/4.png" style="text-align: center;justify-content: center;display: flex;margin: auto;width: 250px;height: 200px;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 5%;">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail">صورة بطاقه الرقم القومى للابن</label>
            <div class="input-group  mb-3">
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" formControlName="fileImageSonNationalId" accept="image/*" class="custom-file-input" id="fileImageSonNationalId" (change)="HandleFileSonid($event, i)" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
                <label class="custom-file-label upload-lbl" for="fileImageSonNationalId">
                       <span *ngIf="img5 !== null" style="margin-right: 50%;">{{img5.name}}</span>
                        <span *ngIf="img5 === null" style="margin-right: 50%;">اختر صورة</span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="group.controls.fileImageSonNationalId.touched && img5 === null">
              صورة بطاقه الرقم القومى مطلوبه
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

this is function of handle file in **component.ts**

```js
 HandleFileSonid(event: any, index: number) {
    if (event.target.files !== null && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      this.img5 = event.target.files[index];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('.imgo').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    } else {
      this.img5 = null;
      $('.imgo').attr('src', '/src/assets/img/4.png');
    }
  }
```

[image]

initialize formarray in **component.ts**

```js
 createItem() {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      nationalId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      phone: ['', [Validators.required]],
      passportNumber: ['', [Validators.required]],
      educationId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      studyId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      birthDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
      mritalStatusId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      genderId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      statusId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      fileImageSonNationalId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      fileImageSonPassPort: ['', [Validators.required]],
      chronic_id21: ['', [Validators.required]],
      prescs1: [false, [Validators.required]],
      operations1: [false, [Validators.required]],
      scan1: [false, [Validators.required]],
      prosthetic1: [false, [Validators.required]],
      physical1: [false, [Validators.required]],
      chronic_id1: ['', [Validators.required]],
      opNameId1: ['', [Validators.required]],
      operCatNameId1: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  addSon() {
    (<FormArray>this.userForm.get('familyMembers')).push(this.createItem());
  }
  removeAddress(index) {
    (<FormArray>this.userForm.get('familyMembers')).removeAt(index);
  }
  get SonArray() {
    return (<FormArray>this.userForm.get('familyMembers')).controls;
  }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: On a glance the reason seems to be  ```this.img5 = event.target.files[index];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('.imgo').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }```

Comment: @TheViralGriffin I know, but what is the solution ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use common selector `$('.imgo')` and change images in all places in one time.
As the way to solve this problem, I suggest, that you add the special id: `id="image-preview-{{ i }}"` for every image preview and use it in your code

I have added needed parts below for changes in html and for handler:

```
<img id="imagu"
  id="image-preview-{{ i }}"
  class="img-fluid imgo "
  src="assets/img/4.png"
  style="text-align: center;justify-content: center;display: flex;margin: auto;width: 250px;height: 200px;" />


HandleFileSonid(event: any, index: number) {
  if (event.target.files !== null && event.target.files.length > 0) {
    this.img5 = event.target.files[index];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#image-preview-' + index).attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  } else {
    this.img5 = null;
    $('#image-preview-' + index).attr('src', '/src/assets/img/4.png');
  }
}
```

Comment: Only the image has changed, but the file name is still the same in all rows

Comment: Using a FileReader to assign a image src is a waste of time, ram & cpu, use URL.createObjectURL instead